# Environment Variable for defining differencing tool in Subversion

Tags: svn, environment-variables

I see that there is the `SVN_EDITOR` environment variable to define what editor to use with subversion, and there's also `SVN_MERGE` environment variable for merging files.

Is there an environment variable for defining the **differencing tool**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can customize the difference tool used by setting `diff-cmd` in your `~/.subversion/config` file; see the [manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.confarea.html#svn.advanced.confarea.opts.config).  You can also use a `--diff-cmd` option on the [command-line](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html).

Comment: I know, thanks.  But I still find it weird that you can set editing and merging through environment variables, but not differencing.

Comment: +1 - there is no environment variable for that, you can try "strings .../svn" to see what strings exist in the binary and figure out which of them are names of environment variables

Comment: @lamcro: yes, it's somewhat odd, but there's a longstanding tradition for editors (and pagers) to be customized from environment variables; difference programs are more specific to SCMs, and the config files are available for that, so there isn't really a need to add yet another way.

Comment: @Ether: Yes, there is a need.
Right now I have then SVN_EDITOR variable configured in the server's default profile for all my programmers.  Yet I would then have to enter to the ~/.subversion/config file of each programmer.
The language we use is pretty archaic(non-text files), and we need special editing or differentiation tools to do our job.

Answer (score 3):

You could also add an alias such as the following to the same default profile:
alias svndiff='svn diff --diff-cmd /usr/bin/meld'